# preserving \n from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have a column called `EventLog  varchar(max)` and can be pretty big because essentially it stores the event log of an entire batch process.

The problem is that when I go into the query window and do a select like this

```
SELECT EventLog from BatchProcess
```

When I cut and paste the text of the event log into Notepad, it

1. removes all of the NewLines `\n` and is just one continous line.
2. only copies a certain amount of text into the clipboard and truncates the rest.

How can I get the content of EventLog from the SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To deal with the truncation try converting it to XML for processing

```
DECLARE @S varchar(max)

SELECT @S = ''

SELECT @S = @S + '
' + EventLog  FROM BatchProcess

SELECT @S AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH('')
```

Code modifed from Martin's Smith's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759721/how-do-i-view-the-full-content-of-a-text-or-varcharmax-column-in-sql-server-200/2760023#2760023)  to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759721/how-do-i-view-the-full-content-of-a-text-or-varcharmax-column-in-sql-server-200

This may also solve the line breaks, but if its a big deal try a different editor

Comment: thank you, this is perfect for my need. I had a look at the log file, it was about 3MB, so I have a feeling SQL Server cuts off anything after one meg.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. removes all of the NewLines and is just one continous line.

That sounds like the typical crappiness of Notepad. IIRC, in order to actually display line breaks, Notepad needs `\r\n` line endings, not just `\n`. Try pasting into WordPad or a [real editor](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Comment: it could've been but i tried it in Word and WordPad also, and it was still continuous lines. The other solution worked though, both for getting the data out and getting the NewLines to appear.

Comment: Copying and pasting doesn't work for me either. I paste into a new SSMS query window, Emacs, or WordPad, and each CRLF is replaced with two spaces. If I use the XML hack, I can see the newlines but my text is polluted by entities. At least I can get the gist, though. I'm using SSMS 2016 (13.0.15900.1) and table view for my results listings.